# python django API authentication post request - output variable displaying json string in browser, but NOT when printed

Tags: python, django, urllib2

```
def test(request):
    u="username"
    p= 'password'
    url='url'
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (u , p )).replace('\n', '')
    d = {}
    req.add_data(d)  //while authentication i dont send any data, but it is treated as POST request only if data is sent, so sending empty data
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string) 
    req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')  
    result = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    print result
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

In browser, the response is coming as (bcoz of HttpResponse)

```
{"token":"abcdef"}  //means correct
```

but the command "print result" is giving something like this :

```
<addinfourl at 140585554707088 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7fdca009e5d0>>
```

So, i am unable to do any operations on that variable . What i want is only the "token" value from the string . I tried :

```
type(result) // error
json.dumps(result)  //error 
json.loads(result)  //error 
token = result.token     //error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should instead use

```
result.read()
```

`result` is the result object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can u plz tell this :
 r = result.read() 
 r = json.loads(r)
 print r // {u'token' : u'dsfksdkfn'}
 So, i have done :  token = r[u'token'] , is it good way to do ?(ofcourse working).